# Django's select_related - filtering references of references

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use Django's select_related to make query that will walk through two separate models.

The conditional looks like this (note, value is a rename - it's not a syntax thing relating to anything about value):

```
if valueResults.objects.select_related("value_id__item_id").filter(status_code="yes", item_id=item_id).exists():
    return JSONResponse({'message':'Yes', 'status':status.HTTP_200_OK})
elif valueResults.objects.select_related("value_id__item_id").filter(status_code="no", item_id=item_id).exists():
    return JSONResponse({'message':'No’, 'status':status.HTTP_200_OK})
else:
    return JSONResponse({'message':'There are no items matching that item_id', 'status': status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND})
```

And the data model looks like this:

```
class valueResults(models.Model):
    value_id = models.ForeignKey(value)
    result_date = EncryptedDateTimeField()
    status_code = EncryptedCharField(max_length=25)
    value = EncryptedIntegerField()
    test_started = EncryptedDateTimeField()

class value(models.Model):
    value_id = EncryptedCharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, max_length=100)
    valuetype_id = models.ForeignKey(valueType)
    dateitemord = EncryptedDateTimeField()
    status = EncryptedCharField(max_length=100)
    item_id = models.ForeignKey(Items)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)

class Items(models.Model):
    item_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=100)
    mailed_date = EncryptedDateTimeField()
    received_date = EncryptedDateTimeField()
    last_viewed = EncryptedDateTimeField()
    dateitemsent = EncryptedDateTimeField()
    itemidvalue = EncryptedCharField(max_length=100)
    itemsent = EncryptedCharField(max_length=25)
    itemret = EncryptedCharField(max_length=25)
    dateitemret = EncryptedDateTimeField()
    status = EncryptedCharField(max_length=25)
```

My ideal goal would be to filter based on the status_code of the valueResults model, and the item_id of the Items. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`select_related` is a performance tuning tool, and not one that has anything to do with existence tests. It doesn't change what kinds of queries are possible. Filtering on foreign key relationships is possible using `__` notation - see the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) for examples. EG, chaining from your `valueResults` model through `value` to `Items`:

```
 if valueResults.objects.filter(value_id__item_id__status="yes", value_id__item_id__item_id=item_id).exists():
     # do something
```

Comment: select_related: Returns a QuerySet that will “follow” foreign-key relationships, selecting additional related-object data when it executes its query. This is a performance booster which results in a single more complex query but means later use of foreign-key relationships won’t require database queries.

Comment: exists(): Returns True if the QuerySet contains any results, and False if not. This tries to perform the query in the simplest and fastest way possible, but it does execute nearly the same query as a normal QuerySet query.

So far as I can tell, as select_related returns a queryset, I should be able to perform an exists() on it.

Comment: It's not semantically incorrect to use `select_related` in an `exists` query, it's just useless. Basically `select_related` expands a normal query to join in related tables. If you're chaining foreign key lookups that will also do the necessary joins. Since you're explicitly listing fields in your `select_related` clause it probably won't do any unnecessary joins, but it certainly won't help anything.